# How to prevent debugging on custom iOS framework

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks, view-debugging

I developed my own iOS framework(for my clients) which provides login and some other features. I imported my framework into a test project and all runs well. In test project I invoked my framework which starts at **InitialViewController** and proceeds to **SignInViewController**.

When **SignInViewController** is displayed I paused the program execution in Xcode.[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CuXj.png)

The problem is I’m able to step into my framework classes while debugging in test project using below statement: [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL5XH.png)

```
(lldb) po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] visibleViewController]

<SignInViewController: 0x7fc225202490>
```

I’m also able to change the property values of SignInViewController: [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9iuI.png)

```
(lldb) po [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] visibleViewController] setGXIdentifier:@"AXSDF"]

AXSDF
```

I sell this framework to my customers and other developers, So I want to

1. Prevent them from debugging my framework in their Xcode projects.
2. Prevent **View debugging** on viewcontrollers of my framework.
3. Prevent changing property values of my viewcontrollers from debugging console.

I tried setting *Generate Debug Symbols* to *NO*. (which does not solve the issue)

I’m looking for a way to disable debugging on my framework.(Btw, I'm using Xcode 9.2)

Comment: You're asking for impossible. Even Apple private api is debugged without problems (and physical cpu registers can be set with arbitrary values at any point in time). You don't need debug symbols to do that. You can try `ptrace` tricks upon initiating your framework https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757919/ptrace-on-ios-8 , but that will make your framework not eligible to be used in an Appstore app.